# How to resove apache2.2 compile error?

Tags: apache-http-server, compile

My requirement is to compile and install httpd 2.2 from source, all the modules must be shared?

Issued configure command like this.

```
./configure --enable-shared-mods="all" --prefix=/path/to/install
```

Configure command executed successfully but when I start to compile it gives me error like this.

```
/bin/sh /usr/local/source3/httpd-2.2.2/shlibtool --silent --mode=link gcc -pthread          -o mod_authn_file.la -rpath /usr/local/task03/modules -module -avoid-version  mod_authn_file.lo 
/bin/sh: /usr/local/source3/httpd-2.2.2/shlibtool: No such file or directory
make[4]: *** [mod_authn_file.la] Error 127
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/source3/httpd-2.2.2/modules/aaa'
make[3]: *** [shared-build-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/source3/httpd-2.2.2/modules/aaa'
make[2]: *** [shared-build-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/source3/httpd-2.2.2/modules'
make[1]: *** [shared-build-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/source3/httpd-2.2.2'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

has apache known to show this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have your reasons for attempting to install version 2.2.2 that was released in April 2006, as opposed to at least 2.2.34 that was released in July 2017, and remains the last release of the Apache 2.2 series that was discontinued at the end of year 2017. But version 2.2.2 will have a lot of known security bugs by now.

The important part seems to be this message:

```
/bin/sh: /usr/local/source3/httpd-2.2.2/shlibtool: No such file or directory
```

So:

- Maybe `/usr/local/source3/httpd-2.2.2/shlibtool` does not exist? But if the configure command completed without errors, that seems unlikely.
- Maybe it's a symbolic link pointing to an invalid target? In that case, what would that target be? Run `ls -l /usr/local/source3/httpd-2.2.2/shlibtool` to see.
- If it's not a symbolic link, perhaps it's a script that specifies an interpreter that does not exist on your system? Look at the first line of `shlibtool` in that case.

Googling on "shlibtool" had this as the first hit: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox//httpd-dev/200107.mbox/%3C000c01c107db$2ca92780$9865fea9@cc230545b%3E

It looks like `shlibtool` might be auto-generated during the configure process if necessary **and you have `libtool` installed on your system**. Do you have libtool installed?

Comment: * /usr/local/source3/httpd-2.2.2/shlibtool does not exist  and libtool is installed (version 2.2.6 release 15.5.ele). I would try to compile it from 2.2.34 and check whether that works.